# Linux Kernel driver modpost missing MODULE_LICENSE

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, compiler-warnings

My Linux Kernel driver (platform driver) contains `MODULE_LICENSE ("GPL v2");`, but during compilation following warning is printed:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/buildroot/output/build/linux-4.15.16'
  LD [M]  /home/me/dir/driver_xy.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /home/me/dir/driver_xy.o
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: With such problem it shouldn't be difficult to prepare [mcve], which demonstrates the problem. Please, do that and add it to the question post.

Comment: Maybe the file you edited and the file you compiled are different files. And by the way, in the above output we don't see an evidence that the module was being compiled.

Comment: this I guess works in Lubuntu 12.04 running kernel 4.4, might be things have changed over years

Answer (score 12):

The Makefile was incorrect: 
The module name was equal the source file name. So following works:

```
#Makefile
obj-m += mymodule.o
mymodule-y := mymodule_main.o driver_xy.o
```

before/incorrect:

```
obj-m += mymodule.o
mymodule-y := driver_xy.o
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");` at the end of my `module.c` file and it worked. See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/issues/812).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33681441)